# Can we make sure two groups are isomorphic if there exists a function which is a bijective homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I'm confused that is a function which is a bijective homomorphism enough to prove the two groups are isomorphic, or we need all possible maps to be bijective homomorphism?

I saw a statement that even though a function $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism, it cannot ensure that the two groups are not isomorphic because there may exist other isomorphisms which hold. Is that true?

I try my best to make my question clear but I've already got myself messy so please forgive and help. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. The map $\phi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\phi(n) = 2n$ is a group homomorphism which is not an isomorphism (it is not bijective). But trivially, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic! If a particular homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to H$ is bijective, then you know $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic because by definition $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. But if a particular homomorphism $\psi\colon G\to H$ is *not* bijective, that does not tell you $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic, it just tells you $\psi$ is not an isomorphism between them.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  A bijective homomorphism *is* an isomorphism.

Comment: "I saw a statement that ..." is not enough information for us to help you figure out what the statement says. If you find it and [edit] the question to include a direct quote perhaps we can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard definition of group isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327232/standard-definition-of-group-isomorphism)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This really solves my problem thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if $\varphi: G\to H$ is a bijective group homomorphism from a group $G$ to a group $H$, then $G\cong H$; its inverse $\varphi^{-1}:H\to G$ is also a bijective homomorphism.

It is not enough to conclude $A\not\cong B$ for groups $A,B$, from just $\psi:A\to B$ not being a bijective homomorphism. For example, for $S_3$ (the symmetric group of degree three) and $D_3$ (the dihedral group of order six), we have $S_3\cong D_3$ despite

$$\begin{align}
\theta:S_3 &\to D_3,\\
x&\mapsto e
\end{align}$$

not being a bijective homomorphism (although it is a homomorphism).

Comment: Thank you so much I finally understand! So we need to prove just one function is bijective homomorphism to show the two groups are isomorphic, but need all maps not bijective homomorphism to show they are not isomorphic.

Comment: You're welcome. Exactly, @NingzeXia.

Answer (score 0):

Two things being isomorphic means that *there exists* a homomorphism which is an isomorphism, not that *all* homomorphisms are isomorphisms. The latter would be quite a useless concept anyway, since between *any* two groups there is always the trivial homomorphism which sends everything to the neutral element. But this map is only an isomorphism if both groups contain only the neutral element. So only trivial groups could be isomorphic.

Comment: I got it thank you so much!!!!!!